# Boggle Rules - Two same letters to make a word

Tags: boggle

Why can't we use two dices at different positions that have the same letters to make a word?

For example:

-DEED --> INVALID

-NEON --> INVALID

Why..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can find nothing in the [official rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/boggle.pdf), nor in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boggle), that disallows using the same letter on different cubes. In fact, the Wikipedia article names some of the longest possible Boggle words and they include multiples of the same letter which would be impossible if that were the case.

It is definitely true that you cannot use the *same* cube more than once in a given word, nor can you spell the same word twice using different cubes. Where did you learn this rule - is it an official online implementation, or from someone telling you the rules, or elsewhere? It's likely that someone misinterpreted the rules, or was playing some kind of variant or house rule.

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Play-Boggle | http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/19589/

Comment: Also, I'm making a Boggle program for a class, and my professor told us that using the same letters (regardless if they are two different dies) twice per word is considered invalid.

Comment: That Wikihow article contradicts itself - it says you can't do NEON, but later on it has APPLE as a valid word. Also, it specifically says you can only use each *die* once, so I suspect the image is at fault (and should actually show an invalid play where the *same* N is used for the start and end of NEON). Similarly, the forum thread also says you can't use the same die, and many of the words found in that grid use the two Ts in the same word.

Comment: So I'd say that that one image in the Wikihow article is wrong, as is your professor (although for the purpose of completing your assignment you should follow your professor's instructions).

Comment: @dendritic This is somewhat tangential but as a IT professional, I would question your professor's requirements to him.  If requirements make no sense, I have found it good practice to question them otherwise the ultimate solution could not be what was really desired.  Understanding requirements is one of the first steps to creating a successful application.  This is a good opportunity to address that less (inadvertantly) if nothing else=)  For the record however, I did give this answer +1 as I agree with it.